# python pipe only stdin,out once, how to do twice or more time

Tags: python, pipeline

success python pipe stdin, out only one time this source

main.py

```
import subprocess from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

player_pipe = subprocess.Popen(["source\call.py", 'arg1'], stdin=PIPE,
     stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)

player_pipe.stdin.write("Send Msg\n")
get_stdout = player_pipe.stdout.readline()
print("[Get Msg]" + get_stdout)

player_pipe.kill()
player_pipe.wait()
```

call.py

```
import sys

getMsg = raw_input()
print getMsg
```

but I want twice or more time stdin, out

so update source but it's not work

What's wrong this source

main.py (update-not work)

```
import subprocess from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

player_pipe = subprocess.Popen(["source\call.py", 'arg1'], stdin=PIPE,
     stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)

player_pipe.stdin.write("Send Msg\n")
get_stdout = player_pipe.stdout.readline()
print("[Get Msg]" + get_stdout)

player_pipe.stdin.write("Send Msg2\n")
get_stdout = player_pipe.stdout.readline()
print("[Get Msg]" + get_stdout)

player_pipe.kill()
player_pipe.wait()
```

call.py(update-not work)

```
import sys

getMsg = raw_input()
print getMsg

getMsg2 = raw_input()
print getMsg2
```

:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the output of `call.py` is buffered. so you have to `flush()` it to send to `main.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import sys

getMsg = raw_input()
print getMsg
sys.stdout.flush()

getMsg2 = raw_input()
print getMsg2
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Note that you need shebang `#!/usr/bin/python2` at least when your OS is Linux (I don't know why OP's code works without shebang. Maybe some Windows magic ?).

Also you can use `-u` option not to buffer the output of python.

```
player_pipe = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python2","-u","./call.py"], stdin=PIPE,
     stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=False)
```

Comment: thanks works well, i don't know why this in window maybe using git bash?

Comment: Windows doesn't seem to require shebang (it probably isn't even recognized by Windows), it uses the default program for this type of files (at least this was my experience with node.js)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "but I want twice or more time stdin, out", I'm not sure what you really mean.

In a basic Linux/UNIX system, you have 1 - and only one - STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR. Now, you can pipe things in and out, treating STDERR separately if you want, but you cannot just arbitrarily assign multiple inputs without setting up separate mechanisms (sockets, etc) to handle that within your program.

Comment: sorry, I'm not good at Linux/Unix System. I can't understand.

Comment: Any reason this limitation exists in Linux/UNIX?  This makes it impossible to read from input, e.g. `input(...)` with python) simply because you have read some data from STDIN early on.  Why is this limitation? I'm suffering the same here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419843/python-crashing-at-input-after-reading-from-stdin/63419985