# Python crashing at `input(...)` after reading from STDIN

Tags: python, linux, stdin, prompt

This does not crash:

```py
import sys
print(len(sys.stdin.read()))
```

But this crashes:

```
import sys
print(len(sys.stdin.read()))
input('lol')
```

with output

```
2300
lolTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test018.py", line 3, in <module>
    input('lol')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Questions:

- Why?
- How to do it right?  My goal is to read some data from STDIN (e.g. `cat somefile | myscript`), and then prompt the user on some matter (e.g. `hey, does this look right?`).

Comment: input in python 2 does that. Do you get the crash when you enter something?

Comment: I don't get get prompted.  BTW, I just tried with Python 2.7.18 and I still get the `EOFError`.  I'm using Linux (not sure if it matters).

Comment: `input()` reads from `sys.stdin` as well. Since you pipe, you can no longer use `input()` to read input from the user. You can instead open `/dev/tty` directly for reading and writing.

Comment: Any easy way to read from TTY?

Comment: @thatotherguy - so I guess the problem is that once STDIN gets piped, it will not get unpiped after EOF is reached?  Any reason Linux behaves so?  To me it seems it would've been better if STDIN was getting unpiped as soon as the pipe returned EOF.  Am I missing some complixities?

Comment: Or.. once STDIN gets piped, why isn't `input(...)`'s STDIN also piped?  I guess pipe would only work once?  Then the pipe constantly returns EOF despite owning the STDIN?

Comment: @caveman - what would it "unpipe" to?

Comment: @caveman - EOF means that the controlling program closed the pipe. most programs wouldn't want a subprocess to somehow reach around them and steal their stdin.

Comment: @tdelaney - who is the controlling program here?

Comment: @caveman - In this case the shell. Its creating a pipe and then does a fork/exec of `cat` with one end of the pipe as stdout. And then a fork/exec of `myscript` with the other end of the pipe as stdin.

Comment: If you look up how file descriptors, pipes, and stdin works in the Unix process model, then all this behavior follows logically and naturally. The behavior you suggest doesn't easily fit in anywhere.

Comment: @tdelaney - Before the STDIN of the fork/exec `myscript` was piped, where was the STDIN?

Comment: If you just ran `myscript` from the shell, it wouldn't touch stdin at all. After fork (before actually executing the program), the subprocess has all of the open file descriptors of the parent. If there is no piping, the shell just exec's `myscript` and it still has those fds. But since there is pipe in `cat somefile |  myscript`, after fork it closes stdin and substitutes the pipe's fd, then executes the program. The shell itself doesn't know when the pipe closes and doesn't really have an opportunity to substitute anything else. Its now just the business of the two connected programs.

Comment: @tdelaney - So, the shell runs my app, and replaces the socket descriptor of STDIN (which is 0 I guess) by another socket descriptor associated with the read side of some pipe (which is some number other than 0 I guess)?  Is this right?

Comment: @caveman - Yes, mostly. File descriptors are integer indexes into a table in the underlying c library. In hand wavy pseudo code, the shell opens a pipe and gets, lets say, file descriptors 4 and 5. It forks and closes 0 and 5 because it doesn't need them. Then it duplicates 4 to 0 meaning that the the file descriptor table entry 4 is duplicated to 0. It then closes 4 to clear up that table entry. Then it executes the new program. Now, when the new program uses file descriptor 0, it get the pipe's entry that has been moved to 0 in the file descriptor table.

Comment: @tdelaney - I see, thanks a lot!  This perfectly answers my question.  So I guess I should just give up the idea of using `input(...)` with pipe.  I may just disable interactive prompts when STDIN is piped, or use TTY prompts instead (separate question).  Off-topic, but I guess the real neat solution would have been if an app had STDIN, STDOUT, PIPEIN, PIPEOUT (or am I re-inventing TTY?).

Comment: Reaching around to the controlling TTY as alaniwi suggests is a common solution on unix. Its more common to disable interactive when run with a PIPE, assuming its running in a script where prompts aren't wanted. You could also use a gui like tkinter and try to pop something up. Or write your own script to execute the command, `myscript "cat somefile"`. Your suggesting is interesting, but I don't know quite how to pull it off.

Answer (score 1):

You have already read from stdin until end of file, but you could read from the terminal device:

```
import sys
print(len(sys.stdin.read()))

print("lol ", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()
answer = open("/dev/tty").readline().replace("\n", "")
print("You typed:", answer)
```

If you pipe stdout also, then you would probably want to write the prompt to the terminal device similarly (note that you would have to open it for writing), although this example uses an ordinary `print` to stdout.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, makes sense that all prompts are on TTY.  But any more cross-platformy way?  Or at least something without me manually writing the path "/dev/tty" as the TTY may not be in that path I guess?  E.g. `getpass()` does it I guess.  But not sure if it has a counterpart for non-passwords.

Comment: @caveman TBH, it seemed that you were using a Unix-like system so I didn't worry too much about cross-platform. I'm afraid I don't know what the terminal device might be called on systems other than Linux, or how to do this more portably, but `/dev/tty` is pretty reliably correct on Linux systems.

Comment: I adopted this solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141331/pipe-input-to-python-program-and-later-get-input-from-user